# Strip filename (shortest) extension by CMake (get filename removing the last extension)

Tags: cmake

[get_filename_component](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/get_filename_component.html?highlight=get_filename_component) can be used to remove/extract the longest extension.

> EXT       = File name longest extension (.b.c from d/a.b.c)
>
> NAME_WE   = File name without directory or longest extension

I have a file with a dot in its name, so I need the shortest extension:

```
set(MYFILE "a.b.c.d")
get_filename_component(MYFILE_WITHOUT_EXT ${MYFILE} NAME_WE)
message(STATUS "${MYFILE_WITHOUT_EXT}")
```

reports

```
-- a
```

but I want

```
-- a.b.c
```

What is the preferred way to find the file name without the shortest extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd solve this with a simple regex:

```
string(REGEX MATCH "^(.*)\\.[^.]*$" dummy ${MYFILE})
set(MYFILE_WITHOUT_EXT ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
```

Comment: I believe it can be done in one line, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 25):

I would do:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "\\.[^.]*$" "" MYFILE_WITHOUT_EXT ${MYFILE})
```

The regular expression matches a dot (`\\.`, see next paragraph), followed by any number of characters that is not a dot `[^.]*` until the end of the string (`$`), and then replaces it with an empty string `""`.

The metacharacter dot (normally in a regular expression it means "match any character") needs to be escaped with a `\` to be interpreted as a literal dot. However, in CMake string literals (like C string literals), `\` is a special character and [need to be escaped as well](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#escape-sequences) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490920/2436175)). Therefore you obtain the weird sequence `\\.`.

Note that (almost all) [metacharacters do not need to be escaped within a Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): therefore we have `[^.]` and not `[^\\.]`.

Finally, note that this expression is safe also if there's no dot in the filename analyzed (the output corresponds to the input string in that case).

Link to [string command documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html).

Comment: You're right, the one-liner works as well. But the need to double backslashes has nothing to do with C string literals - it's simply the fact that backslash is also CMake's escape character that causes it.

Comment: @Angew Are you saying that [the answer I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490793/cmake-how-to-get-the-backslash-literal-in-regexp-replace/4490920#4490920) is wrong?

Comment: Yes; I commented to that effect on the answer.

Comment: @Angew I edited my answer, I found the correct reference in cmake documentation

Comment: Incidentally, if you're just trying to _change_ the extension (as opposed to removing it entirely) you can do `STRING(REGEX REPLACE "[^.]*$" "newext" MYFILE_WITH_NEW_EXT ${MYFILE_WITH_OLD_EXT})` (you don't need the `\\.`). Is that useful? Not particularly, but I thought it was neat.

Comment: @NicHartley It doesn't really work if the extension is missing in the original file: in that case your new file name becomes newext!!

Comment: @Antonio If you're trying to change the extension, that implies there was one to begin with. That's mostly pointless pedantry, though.

Comment: @NicHartley That's a thing you can be sure of only if you do a sanity check on your input arguments

Answer (score 10):

As of [CMake 3.14](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/get_filename_component.html) it is possible to do this with `get_filename_component` directly.

**`NAME_WLE`: File name without directory or last extension**

```
set(INPUT_FILE a.b.c.d)
get_filename_component(OUTPUT_FILE_WE ${INPUT_FILE} NAME_WE)
get_filename_component(OUTPUT_FILE_WLE ${INPUT_FILE} NAME_WLE)
```

`OUTPUT_FILE_WE` would be set to `a`, and `OUTPUT_FILE_WLE` would be set to `a.b.c`.

Answer (score 4):

In CMake 3.20 and greater, the [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html#get-stem) command now provides an elegant solution:

> ```
>  cmake_path(GET <path-var> STEM [LAST_ONLY] <out-var>)
> ```

where `STEM` refers to the portion of the filename before the extension. The `cmake_path` command supersedes the `get_filename_component` command.

So, in your example `a.b.c.d`, the following code grabs the stem of the filename:

```
cmake_path(GET MYFILE STEM MYFILE_WITHOUT_EXT)
message(STATUS ${MYFILE_WITHOUT_EXT})
```

which yields:

```
a
```

But this code with `LAST_ONLY` grabs the stem, but considers only the last extension as the file extension:

```
cmake_path(GET MYFILE STEM LAST_ONLY MYFILE_WITHOUT_EXT)
message(STATUS ${MYFILE_WITHOUT_EXT})
```

which yields:

```
a.b.c
```