# Version regular expression in CMake

Tags: regex, cmake

I want to validate user-specified version string - to ensure it consists of three period-separated numbers (`e.g. 1.20.300`). 
But i'm not sure how to write such regex, the code below is just a try:

```
if( PROJECT_VERSION MATCHES "([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9+])" )
    message( "NOTE: Valid version string" )
else()
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Invalid version string" )
endif()
```

So, how to correctly write required regex?
Thanks.

**UPD**
My regex also matches `1.2.3.4`, but is should not! 
Only three period-separated numbers are possible.

Comment: try `"^([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)$"`

Comment: @Biffen It also matches `1.2.3.4` string, for example. But is shouldn't!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dots are special in regex, so you should escape them:

```
"^([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)$"
```

Why double-backslash?  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490920/4323

Comment: Ok, looks like it works! :) Can you briefly explain why you use `^` and `$`?
Also, i still can't understand what regex syntax dialect CMake supports. E.g. there is no `\d` (any digit) operator here

Comment: `^` and `$` mean "beginning" and "end" of the string respectively.  This prevents matching rubbish like abc1.2.3xyz.

Comment: Got it. This is the reason why my original regex matches 1.2.3**.4**. Thanks!