# CMake - Check if Pylint is installed

Tags: cmake, pylint

I'm using Cmake to go through all the .py files inside a directory and detect errors and check coding standards using Pylint.

Is there a way for me to check if Pylint is installed using cmake? Would this code be OS independent (for example for Ubuntu and Windows)?

Comment: Have a look at CMake's findLatex file, there you can learn how to check for an executable. You can run it using execute_command. Examples for the latter are in FindDoxygen and FindGit from recent CMake versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a FindPylint.cmake file and `include()` its directory. Then run `find_package(Pylint REQUIRED)`.

FindPylint.cmake:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND pylint --version
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE pylint_out
    RESULT_VARIABLE pylint_error
    ERROR_VARIABLE pylint_suppress)

if (NOT pylint_error)
    string(REGEX MATCH "pylint .\..\.." pylint_version_string "${pylint_out}")
    string(SUBSTRING "${pylint_version_string}" 7 5 pylint_version)
endif ()

if (pylint_version)
    set(PYLINT_FOUND 1
        CACHE INTERNAL "Pylint version ${pylint_version} found")
endif ()

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(Pylint REQUIRED_VARS pylint_version
                                    VERSION_VAR pylint_version)
```

Some explanation:

- The error output is not actually an error, it reads `No config file found, using default configuration`, so we suppress it by ignoring the `pylint_suppress` variable.
- the `pylint` output has more than just the version, so we need to do some regex/string handling.
- the `CACHE INTERNAL` variable is not strictly necessary, but could come in handy later to check if Pylint was found.

Comment: Try this: `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})`

Comment: That worked! Now I'm getting this: `Syntax error in cmake code at

    .../FindPylint.cmake:8

  when parsing string

    pylint .\..\..

  Invalid escape sequence \.`

Comment: which version of CMake?

Comment: I'm using  version 3.5.1

Comment: I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477207/version-regular-expression-in-cmake 

You might need two `\\' to escape the 'dot'. Weird, since it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

find_package ( Pylint )

if ( PYLINT_FOUND )
  message ( STATUS "pylint version: ${PYLINT_VERSION}" )
endif ()
```

And in the same directory add **FindPylint.cmake**:

```
# - Find Pylint
# Find the Pylint executable and extract the version number
#
# OUTPUT Variables
#
#   PYLINT_FOUND
#       True if the pylint package was found
#   PYLINT_EXECUTABLE
#       The pylint executable location
#   PYLINT_VERSION
#       A string denoting the version of pylint that has been found

find_program ( PYLINT_EXECUTABLE pylint PATHS /usr/bin )

if ( PYLINT_EXECUTABLE )
  execute_process ( COMMAND ${PYLINT_EXECUTABLE} --version OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYLINT_VERSION_RAW ERROR_QUIET )
  if (PYLINT_VERSION_RAW)
    string ( REGEX REPLACE "^pylint ([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+),.*" "\\1" PYLINT_VERSION ${PYLINT_VERSION_RAW})
  else ()
    set ( PYLINT_VERSION "unknown" )
  endif()
endif ()

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS ( Pylint DEFAULT_MSG PYLINT_EXECUTABLE )

mark_as_advanced ( PYLINT_EXECUTABLE PYLINT_VERSION )
```

Based on this [code](https://code.ornl.gov/mantidproject/mantid/blob/1818a2a1f761c812022af9f61247855727276496/buildconfig/CMake/FindPylint.cmake).