# cmake how to exclude ._ files in macos in FILE(GLOB ) directive

Tags: regex, cmake

In my cmake C++ project, I am adding source files to target by

```
file(GLOB HEADERS *.h)
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```

In macOS this is including files like `._Source.cpp` and `._Header.h` I tried the REGEX

```
list(FILTER HEADERS REGEX "^[^\.].+" output_variable HEADERS)
list(FILTER SOURCES REGEX "^[^\.].+" output_variable SOURCES)
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Isn't that `list(FILTER HEADERS INCLUDE REGEX "^[^\.].+")`?

Comment: @Florian This gave `list sub-command FILTER requires list to be present.` error

Comment: @Florian I have corrected the syntax but still `list(FILTER HEADERS EXCLUDE REGEX "^[\.].+")` has no effect. still `._` files are being included

Comment: `list(FILTER HEADERS EXCLUDE REGEX "^\\..+")`? I forgot that CMake needs double backslash, because it evaluates escape sequences first.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490793/cmake-how-to-get-the-backslash-literal-in-regexp-replace)

Comment: I have used backslash to escape `.` inside `[]`. doesn't it needed?

Comment: I don't think you need the `[]` (any-of-expression) because you only check for a single character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135039/discussion-between-necktwi-and-florian).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

```
file(GLOB HEADERS RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "*.h") 
file(GLOB SOURCES RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "*.cpp") 

list(FILTER HEADERS EXCLUDE REGEX "^\\..+") 
list(FILTER SOURCES EXCLUDE REGEX "^\\..+"
```

- The `list(FILTER ...)` needs `INCLUDE` or `EXCLUDE` keyword
- The `file(GLOB ...)` by default will return full paths, so you need to add the `RELATIVE` keyword
- The regex needs double backslashs, because CMake evaluates escape sequences first
- You don't need the `[]` (any-of-expression) because you only check for a single character

**Reference**

- [CMake: how to get the backslash literal in Regexp replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490793/cmake-how-to-get-the-backslash-literal-in-regexp-replace)

Comment: list(FILTER ...) was introduced in cmake 3.6